# SQL Reporting Services Report Parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I'm rebuilding an application that allows a user to generate a report based on a little mini-query.  Do SSRS report parameters support selection of the comparison predicate?  My users need to be able to search where a given attribute equals, does not equal, is greater than, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but I think you could replicate it, verbose as it may be. To start, you would have a parameter that specifies the comparison operator (explicit list or a query to available options). Then you would have to use an ugly set of `OR` checks in your query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Table]
WHERE
    (@Operator IS NULL) /* All rows if no operator, or some default condition */
    OR
    (@Operator = '=' AND [Field] = [Value])
    OR
    (@Operator = '<' AND [Field] < [Value])
    OR
    (@Operator = '>' AND [Field] > [Value])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can certainly accommodate that.

First, add a parameter with the comparison options. Let's call it `@Operator`.

Next, add conditions to your query `WHERE` clause to handle the situations. Something like:

```
WHERE ((@Operator = '=' and Col1 = @Parameter) OR (@Operator = '!=' and Col1 != @Parameter) ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be dynamic SQL and actually use the operator parameter directly to build the SQL statement.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Attribute] ' + @operator + @value
EXEC (@SQL)
```